# Django annotate: sum of max of foreign objects

Tags: django, django-orm

```
class CashEvent(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    profit = models.FloatField()
    damage = models.FloatField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller)


class Seller(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)


class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

From the models above, given that in `ids` I have a list of ids of `Seller`s, I need to annotate this list so that I have **the sum of each highest damage of each single Seller** in my list.

Is this possible to do in annotate?

```
ids = [4, 5, 6]

Store.objects.filter(
    seller__id__in=ids
).annotate(
    sum_of_highest_damage_of_each_seller=?
)
```

I have tried with `Sum(Max('seller__cashevent__damage'))` but you can't put an aggregation function inside of another.

Comment: Hi Sayurnix, you are looking for window function, self explanatory: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions